# RegEx to replace text between two hash-symbols, between two tags, but keep everything else

Tags: regex, replace, coldfusion, full-text-search

So I need to replace #var# and #var2# with `<cfqueryparam value="#var#" />` and `<cfqueryparam value="#var2#" />`. However, this should only happen when #var# is wrapped inside `<cfquery></cfquery>`.

As an extra criteria, the cfquery-tag will contain text before and after the hash-symbols. This is an example:

```
<cfquery datasource="#tablename#">
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = #var#, somethingelse = #var2#;
</cfquery>
```

I need a regex that only **matches** 'test' when it's between two hash-symbols and inside a cfquery-tag that may or may not have attributes.

I'm using grepWin to do the replacement.

Comment: Use an XML parser to parse your XML. Then use regex to process the "plain" content of the tag.

Comment: For the example you showed, there would probably be single quotes around the variable.  You probably have other queries where there will not be.  You also are not doing anything about datatypes or null attributes.  Plus it's possible to have variables in queries used in a way where query parameters are inappropriate.  All things considered, this looks like a bad plan.

Comment: Will look into it, thanks! I have about 1000 files to do this for. Any programs come to mind that will do the XML parsing and regex-process within sub-folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Another solution with regex:**

You can use the following to match:

```
(#[^#><]*#)(?=[^>]*<\/cfquery>)
```

And replace with:

```
<cfqueryparam value="$1" />
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yO1yL8/1)

Comment: This is nice! Straight to the point and answers what I asked. Thank you!

Comment: Very nice solution, like how you added a demo! +1

Comment: Glad you think so.. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Strategy**

You could use `awk` it's simple enough. In pseudo code we will try the following:

```
look for occurrence of cfquery
substitute as desired
until /cfquery is found
```

**Script**

This results in following script:

```
in_query {
    $0 = gensub(/(#[^#]+#)/, "<cfqueryparam value=\"\\1\" />", "g", $0)
}
/<cfquery.*>/ {
    in_query = 1
}
/<\/ *cfquery.*>/ {
    in_query = ""
}
{
    print $0
}
```

**Usage**

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Comment: My pleasure, `awk` is a powerful tool!