# Replace only hard returns between two tags using grep/regex

Tags: regex, grep

I would all of the data between `<item>` and `</item>` in an .xml file to be on one line (i.e. replace each \r with \t). So instead of this:

```
    <item>
        <title>Image</title>
        <link>http://www.somewebsite.com/?post_type=acf-field&#038;p=23</link>
        <pubDate>Thu, 06 Aug 2015 15:19:17 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[joey]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.somewebsite.com/?post_type=acf-field&#038;p=23</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[a:16:{s:4:"type";s:5:"image";s:12:"instructions";s:48:"Image size should be 1110px wide by 1154px tall.";s:8:"required";i:0;s:17:"conditional_logic";i:0;s:7:"wrapper";a:3:{s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:5:"class";s:0:"";s:2:"id";s:0:"";}s:13:"parent_layout";s:13:"55c37498bba7e";s:13:"return_format";s:2:"id";s:12:"preview_size";s:6:"medium";s:7:"library";s:3:"all";s:9:"min_width";s:0:"";s:10:"min_height";s:0:"";s:8:"min_size";s:0:"";s:9:"max_width";s:0:"";s:10:"max_height";s:0:"";s:8:"max_size";s:0:"";s:10:"mime_types";s:0:"";}]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[image]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id>23</wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>2015-08-06 15:19:17</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>2015-08-06 15:19:17</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>field_55c374e5aecef</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>22</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>acf-field</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
    </item>
```

I would like this:

```
<item>  <title>Image</title>    <link>http://www.somewebsite.com/?post_type=acf-field&#038;p=23</link>  <pubDate>Thu, 06 Aug 2015 15:19:17 +0000</pubDate>  <dc:creator><![CDATA[joey]]></dc:creator>   <guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.somewebsite.com/?post_type=acf-field&#038;p=23</guid> <description></description> <content:encoded><![CDATA[a:16:{s:4:"type";s:5:"image";s:12:"instructions";s:48:"Image size should be 1110px wide by 1154px tall.";s:8:"required";i:0;s:17:"conditional_logic";i:0;s:7:"wrapper";a:3:{s:5:"width";s:0:"";s:5:"class";s:0:"";s:2:"id";s:0:"";}s:13:"parent_layout";s:13:"55c37498bba7e";s:13:"return_format";s:2:"id";s:12:"preview_size";s:6:"medium";s:7:"library";s:3:"all";s:9:"min_width";s:0:"";s:10:"min_height";s:0:"";s:8:"min_size";s:0:"";s:9:"max_width";s:0:"";s:10:"max_height";s:0:"";s:8:"max_size";s:0:"";s:10:"mime_types";s:0:"";}]]></content:encoded>   <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[image]]></excerpt:encoded>    <wp:post_id>23</wp:post_id> <wp:post_date>2015-08-06 15:19:17</wp:post_date>    <wp:post_date_gmt>2015-08-06 15:19:17</wp:post_date_gmt>    <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status> <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>   <wp:post_name>field_55c374e5aecef</wp:post_name>    <wp:status>publish</wp:status>  <wp:post_parent>22</wp:post_parent> <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>    <wp:post_type>acf-field</wp:post_type>  <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>   <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>  </item>
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506640/regex-to-replace-text-between-two-hash-symbols-between-two-tags-but-keep-every) got me close but I am still learning regex commands and cannot figure it out.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is this the whole document, or are there more `<item>` nodes? Can they be nested?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: @ hek2mgl Good question– this is for the whole document. I have over 1,000 groups to take care of. Actually I don't think they are nested.

Comment: @ Jan The file is XML and I am using TextWrangler to search and replace.

Comment: What if, for example, the description tag has a value containing newlines?

Comment: @ glenn jackman Good point. I did a search, though, and there is no data between any of the `<description>` tags so fortunately I don't have to worry about that for this file.

Answer (score 1):

Having that the item nodes don't appear nested, meaning `item` nodes doesn't contain other `item` nodes, you can use this `sed` command:

```
sed '/<item>/{:a;N;/<\/item>/!ba;s/\n/\t/g;}' file.xml
```

When the pattern `<item>` occurs in the file the block between the `{ ... }` gets executed.

`:a` defines a label, `N` reads the next line and appends it to the pattern buffer. `/<\/item>/` checks for the closing `</item>` node in the pattern buffer. If it is not found (`!`), `ba` branches back to the label `a`.

Once the closing `<item>` tag is reached, `s/\n/\t/g` replaces all newlines in the pattern buffer by tabs.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer. I am, however, getting this error message: `sed: 1: "/<item>/{:a;N;/<\/item> ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`. I am researching how to resolve this but if you have time to explain what else I might be doing wrong, I would really appreciate it. Thank you again.

Comment: @ hek2mgl Thank you so much for your help. I got it working but only after I entered each command on a separate line– like you see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467616/sed-gives-me-unexpected-eof-pending-s-error-and-i-have-no-idea-why. I greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: I use a Mac with OS 10.10 and Terminal.